# How can I custom the grid for each gallery in node gallery?

Tags: 7, media

I'm working on d7 with the [node gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery) module.  It works fine, however by default all galleries created with node gallery display with the same number of columns configured in the view.  If in the view the grid has 3 columns all galleries created with node gallery will have 3 colums.

I want for example the gallery1 has 3 columns and the gallery2 has 4 columns, and the gallery3 be 5 columns, etc.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "custom the columns of the grid"? If that's something purely css-related, it would be off-topic here, but honestly, I have no idea.

Comment: I can create galleries with the module node gallery.  I want for example the gallery1 the grid of the view be 3 columns and the gallery2 the grid of the view be 4 columns, and the grid of the gallery3 be 5 columns, etc.  Currently, all galleries have the same columns in the grid.  Are you understanding me?

Comment: Please use **[edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/138412/edit)** to provide clarifications. Not comments.